# Remove \r and \n (CRLF) from serial input

Tags: go, serial-port, newline

I'm currently writing Go code which reads a sensor value through an Arduino using the serial port. Currently I am getting "\r" and "\n" in my output. I know in Python, you can do:

```
line = line.decode('utf-8')
```

to get rid of the characters. How would you do that using Golang? I'm fairly new to the language so any help would be appreciated! Here is what a snippet of the output looks like currently:

```
"arduinoLED\"}\r\n{\"temperature\"
```

Also if anyone could let me know how I can read a line in Go (similar to Python's `line.readline()`) that would be great.

Many thanks!

Comment: Here's the prescribed way to read a stream by lines - https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines

Comment: `line.decode('utf-8')` doesn't remove newline characters, it just decodes the bytes as utf8, which in this case does essentially nothing.

Comment: Your title makes no sense in relation to the question.  You read input, not *"output"*.  Input and *"output"* are relative to the CPU (that's executing your program), not the peripheral device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read a stream by lines using a [default `bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines) (which is the usual way) then both regular (`\n`) and CRLF (`\r\n`) line breaks will be discarded:

```
doc := "Hello\nWorld!\nGoodbye,\r\nnewlines!\r\n"

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader([]byte(doc)))
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", scanner.Text()) // Note our own newline here
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    panic(err) // TODO: handle error properly
}

// Prints:
// "Hello,"
// "World!"
// "Goodbye,"
// "newlines!"
```

Of course, instead of the bytes reader in the example above you'll probably have an existing Reader but the usage should be identical otherwise.

Comment: Thank you! The bufio.Scanner has removed the CRLF line breaks. However, my code currently looks like this:
`buf := make([]byte, 100)`
`n, _ := port.Read(buf)`
`scanner := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader([]byte(buf[:n])))`

I am scanning in the characters from slice that has a static size. How do you take the stream of characters directly from the serial port and not the slice? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your "port" is a reader, see if you can do `bufio.NewScanner(port)`...